# Cant build Firebreath when including libgpgme

Tags: macos, firebreath, gpgme

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_libintl_dgettext", referenced from:
      _gpg_strerror in libgpg-error.a(libgpg_error_la-strerror.o)
      _gpg_strerror_r in libgpg-error.a(libgpg_error_la-strerror.o)
      _gpg_strsource in libgpg-error.a(libgpg_error_la-strsource.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As stated by the question , When trying to build my firebreath project which requires libgpgme on MacOSX 10.6 using Xcode I get the error above. My include/search paths are valid since I can run the following command from the console and it works fine.

```
 g++ -o test test.cpp `gpgme-config --libs`
```

The output form the gpgme-config is -L/opt/local/lib -lgpgme -lassuan -lgpg-error. Not sure what other info is needed , comment and I will updated as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're building a universal binary for both 32 and 64 bit and the library you're including is not built for 64 bit.  You can build i386 only by adding -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386" to your prepmac.sh command-line.

Make sure to delete your build directory before running prepmac.sh with the new argument or it may not take.

See the [Prep Scripts](http://www.firebreath.org/x/X4AG) page on firebreath.org for more info.

Comment: Thanks pointer, I need to get the i386 libs , I currently only had x64 libs installed so build was ok for x64 but failing for i386.

Comment: according to your message it's the other way around; that error is saying that your x86_64 libraries aren't there.

Comment: it may not even be specifically the gpgme that is missing it; look at the symbols that it says it can't find and those are missing on 64 bit

Comment: yeah it seems its the gettext lib , trying to work out how to compile it for i386 arch